# WordPress - How To Allow Header And Footer Sections To Be Edited

Tags: wordpress

I was just wondering what approach people take when it comes to making the header and footer sections editable within WordPress?

For most sites these areas are static and the client does not want or need to amend them.

I do have the awesome Advanced Custom Fields plugin installed and am not sure if that can be utilised?

All suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're happy with ACF, I'd probably look at the (premium) [ACF Options Page](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/) plugin.  That'd let you add fields for defining your header and footer content in a single place (a separate options page).

Comment: Both the answer below and this one are great solutions.  Thanks very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add two widgets, one to the header and one to the footer. This can be done by adding the following to the `functions.php` file:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Header information', 'twentytwelve' ),
    'id' => 'header-information',
    'description' => __( 'Information for the header', 'twentytwelve' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Footer information', 'twentytwelve' ),
    'id' => 'footer-information',
    'description' => __( 'Information for the footer', 'twentytwelve' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

Then add

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'header-information' );
```

to the `header.php` file and

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-information' );
```

to the `footer.php` file

Then in the widgets section on the backend you can add widgets to the header and footer sections. With that you can add/remove images/text etc from the header/footer.